# Device names in MSYS2 dd

Tags: dd, mingw, msys, coreutils

Which is the equivalent of:

```
dd if=/dev/sda   ...
dd if=/dev/sda1  ...
```

for `dd.exe` in [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/) in [coreutils](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/tree/master/coreutils)

Does [Chrysocome](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) syntax apply?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The device names are the same as in Linux, so your original commands should work as-is (no need for equivalents).

You should be able to look up the device and partition names by reading `/proc/` files:

```
$ more /proc/partitions
$ more /proc/devices
$ more /proc/mounts
```

Comment: `/proc/partitions` is the correct answer, the names will not be listed as `/dev` in the other pseudofiles.